# Using a link data path to access a link that is web-scraped using python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The output seems to be a data path for a link. I am not sure given I am very new to web scraping and python. How do I use the output to access the link that it is directed to using python?

Page Source information

[image]

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, 'lxml')
    return soupdata


soup = make_soup(
    "https://www.bahamas.gov.bs/wps/portal/public/!ut/p/b1/vZTbkqo4FIafpR-AJuHsJQKikASQBIUby7OiNAooh6cf9lRXTe2e6nYu9pB1lcq_6sv610r4hF_yycf6eT6uq3P-sb7-2ifKSgQ21nVJw55AR2AGDai4TAaaqfSCuBeAb5YOfs-3ZaCAGfOR7qtTwXMFfsEvp3GBjBzXlm6snHJf38UsiZuJizgnQS1y8nMmmcvlaipAv65rE2utc9vm3kVzTgdDHZ2kKJ44682y3chysjMemFM2N3pD4-cKJQwzAe8uz8k4bh60Kq14mnjdoyDciCqWYqQm2IDDBLqkfVzePuv54cJ_12N7ODD6Y02RfvlBycy0fNEW4df8r4ZJ_zH_e8GLfiz45EfLJfAp-KllryAvBBJPpnm25-Nepn4rGwOe8ksgrcK0vc26SzdPQePiLpoR02oBYnXIOkao1bePkDINWkAjJ7zITsgaTGggVBX1d9GcjXVjfJXm6c_AECnDArUxHBqo_u9AVxB7IBIR0QwY2uLAQO3PD43DJ-dN9l5vs3fwro1EYSSrQJM0KEMA-SiNlcYsZ7VlkdVpzy42ybcbZDRabV8NUNCrNXe310lLt8-D1d6yxqbqfjOeOJxie5Gk68nuut6LxwVg-63PHgk24rUebB1WcfNAyF2ke8gvSGHUSmCtqKSV482OMTLlan3ZhPfd5Bmt0706D65GgWLiHXarnE63DWbX2JdULTufmpbQZ-TeMA2jBEwTuGDhIS-5c5oQM8EOKg57Rd0WGVe11aN5MUbmv8eoCwCmvck07mDH6vLSLXqTRVKtITVjCDasxqwEuMNi1c0J3U0_TTZ989g-Xr1MaVigRpWhgeLAQBEMDRSGBsoDA52hp1T88-_wt89OBhAKItRkQVQVVeCjHhWkWp27YVazNApIeHyi0QFRXEShpvoRXeQtFh0XxtA1UpdCC4bWpQzD9oasU0RY6nVt5XThc57Ws869FH05ATn44k66gZN0z-2MGYprcHBs0DJf3I8fsve460eduI8Q1m9v_C1jT9dFytw6mMvun9ivua8R_wVxbY3o/dl4/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/")

link = soup.find('div', {"class": "module"}).findAll('a')[0]
url_req = link.get('href')
print(url_req)
```

Output:

```
?1dmy&urile=wcm%3apath%3a/mof_content/internet/moh/government/news+and+press+release/covid-19+report+update+227
```

Answer (score 0):

When scraping an href, the initial link need to be combined with the output

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, 'lxml')
    return soupdata


soup = make_soup(
    "https://www.bahamas.gov.bs/wps/portal/public/!ut/p/b1/vZTbkqo4FIafpR-AJuHsJQKikASQBIUby7OiNAooh6cf9lRXTe2e6nYu9pB1lcq_6sv610r4hF_yycf6eT6uq3P-sb7-2ifKSgQ21nVJw55AR2AGDai4TAaaqfSCuBeAb5YOfs-3ZaCAGfOR7qtTwXMFfsEvp3GBjBzXlm6snHJf38UsiZuJizgnQS1y8nMmmcvlaipAv65rE2utc9vm3kVzTgdDHZ2kKJ44682y3chysjMemFM2N3pD4-cKJQwzAe8uz8k4bh60Kq14mnjdoyDciCqWYqQm2IDDBLqkfVzePuv54cJ_12N7ODD6Y02RfvlBycy0fNEW4df8r4ZJ_zH_e8GLfiz45EfLJfAp-KllryAvBBJPpnm25-Nepn4rGwOe8ksgrcK0vc26SzdPQePiLpoR02oBYnXIOkao1bePkDINWkAjJ7zITsgaTGggVBX1d9GcjXVjfJXm6c_AECnDArUxHBqo_u9AVxB7IBIR0QwY2uLAQO3PD43DJ-dN9l5vs3fwro1EYSSrQJM0KEMA-SiNlcYsZ7VlkdVpzy42ybcbZDRabV8NUNCrNXe310lLt8-D1d6yxqbqfjOeOJxie5Gk68nuut6LxwVg-63PHgk24rUebB1WcfNAyF2ke8gvSGHUSmCtqKSV482OMTLlan3ZhPfd5Bmt0706D65GgWLiHXarnE63DWbX2JdULTufmpbQZ-TeMA2jBEwTuGDhIS-5c5oQM8EOKg57Rd0WGVe11aN5MUbmv8eoCwCmvck07mDH6vLSLXqTRVKtITVjCDasxqwEuMNi1c0J3U0_TTZ989g-Xr1MaVigRpWhgeLAQBEMDRSGBsoDA52hp1T88-_wt89OBhAKItRkQVQVVeCjHhWkWp27YVazNApIeHyi0QFRXEShpvoRXeQtFh0XxtA1UpdCC4bWpQzD9oasU0RY6nVt5XThc57Ws869FH05ATn44k66gZN0z-2MGYprcHBs0DJf3I8fsve460eduI8Q1m9v_C1jT9dFytw6mMvun9ivua8R_wVxbY3o/dl4/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/")

link = soup.find('div', {"class": "module"}).findAll('a')[0]
temp = link.get('href')
print(temp)

url_req = "https://www.bahamas.gov.bs/wps/portal/public/!ut/p/b1/vZTbkqo4FIafpR-AJuHsJQKikASQBIUby7OiNAooh6cf9lRXTe2e6nYu9pB1lcq_6sv610r4hF_yycf6eT6uq3P-sb7-2ifKSgQ21nVJw55AR2AGDai4TAaaqfSCuBeAb5YOfs-3ZaCAGfOR7qtTwXMFfsEvp3GBjBzXlm6snHJf38UsiZuJizgnQS1y8nMmmcvlaipAv65rE2utc9vm3kVzTgdDHZ2kKJ44682y3chysjMemFM2N3pD4-cKJQwzAe8uz8k4bh60Kq14mnjdoyDciCqWYqQm2IDDBLqkfVzePuv54cJ_12N7ODD6Y02RfvlBycy0fNEW4df8r4ZJ_zH_e8GLfiz45EfLJfAp-KllryAvBBJPpnm25-Nepn4rGwOe8ksgrcK0vc26SzdPQePiLpoR02oBYnXIOkao1bePkDINWkAjJ7zITsgaTGggVBX1d9GcjXVjfJXm6c_AECnDArUxHBqo_u9AVxB7IBIR0QwY2uLAQO3PD43DJ-dN9l5vs3fwro1EYSSrQJM0KEMA-SiNlcYsZ7VlkdVpzy42ybcbZDRabV8NUNCrNXe310lLt8-D1d6yxqbqfjOeOJxie5Gk68nuut6LxwVg-63PHgk24rUebB1WcfNAyF2ke8gvSGHUSmCtqKSV482OMTLlan3ZhPfd5Bmt0706D65GgWLiHXarnE63DWbX2JdULTufmpbQZ-TeMA2jBEwTuGDhIS-5c5oQM8EOKg57Rd0WGVe11aN5MUbmv8eoCwCmvck07mDH6vLSLXqTRVKtITVjCDasxqwEuMNi1c0J3U0_TTZ989g-Xr1MaVigRpWhgeLAQBEMDRSGBsoDA52hp1T88-_wt89OBhAKItRkQVQVVeCjHhWkWp27YVazNApIeHyi0QFRXEShpvoRXeQtFh0XxtA1UpdCC4bWpQzD9oasU0RY6nVt5XThc57Ws869FH05ATn44k66gZN0z-2MGYprcHBs0DJf3I8fsve460eduI8Q1m9v_C1jT9dFytw6mMvun9ivua8R_wVxbY3o/dl4/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/" + temp
print(url_req)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `urllib.parse.urljoin` to get the absolute link from the relative link.

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, 'lxml')
    return soupdata

web_url = "https://www.bahamas.gov.bs/wps/portal/public/!ut/p/b1/vZTbkqo4FIafpR-AJuHsJQKikASQBIUby7OiNAooh6cf9lRXTe2e6nYu9pB1lcq_6sv610r4hF_yycf6eT6uq3P-sb7-2ifKSgQ21nVJw55AR2AGDai4TAaaqfSCuBeAb5YOfs-3ZaCAGfOR7qtTwXMFfsEvp3GBjBzXlm6snHJf38UsiZuJizgnQS1y8nMmmcvlaipAv65rE2utc9vm3kVzTgdDHZ2kKJ44682y3chysjMemFM2N3pD4-cKJQwzAe8uz8k4bh60Kq14mnjdoyDciCqWYqQm2IDDBLqkfVzePuv54cJ_12N7ODD6Y02RfvlBycy0fNEW4df8r4ZJ_zH_e8GLfiz45EfLJfAp-KllryAvBBJPpnm25-Nepn4rGwOe8ksgrcK0vc26SzdPQePiLpoR02oBYnXIOkao1bePkDINWkAjJ7zITsgaTGggVBX1d9GcjXVjfJXm6c_AECnDArUxHBqo_u9AVxB7IBIR0QwY2uLAQO3PD43DJ-dN9l5vs3fwro1EYSSrQJM0KEMA-SiNlcYsZ7VlkdVpzy42ybcbZDRabV8NUNCrNXe310lLt8-D1d6yxqbqfjOeOJxie5Gk68nuut6LxwVg-63PHgk24rUebB1WcfNAyF2ke8gvSGHUSmCtqKSV482OMTLlan3ZhPfd5Bmt0706D65GgWLiHXarnE63DWbX2JdULTufmpbQZ-TeMA2jBEwTuGDhIS-5c5oQM8EOKg57Rd0WGVe11aN5MUbmv8eoCwCmvck07mDH6vLSLXqTRVKtITVjCDasxqwEuMNi1c0J3U0_TTZ989g-Xr1MaVigRpWhgeLAQBEMDRSGBsoDA52hp1T88-_wt89OBhAKItRkQVQVVeCjHhWkWp27YVazNApIeHyi0QFRXEShpvoRXeQtFh0XxtA1UpdCC4bWpQzD9oasU0RY6nVt5XThc57Ws869FH05ATn44k66gZN0z-2MGYprcHBs0DJf3I8fsve460eduI8Q1m9v_C1jT9dFytw6mMvun9ivua8R_wVxbY3o/dl4/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh"
soup = make_soup(web_url)

link = soup.find('div', {"class": "module"}).findAll('a')[0]
url_req = link.get('href')

absolute_link = urllib.parse.urljoin(web_url, url_req)
```